# How to assign user rights to a local user account through powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to modify the user rights associated with a local user account.I want to add groups and users to a particular User Rights. This is done by opening the group policy and opening the following folder in the console tree: Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment. Then click on the required user Right and add the user or group to it.

Is it possible to do the same through powershell scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is open SecPol.msc, make your modifications via the GUI to a baseline computer and export an .inf template for installation via powershell.

The template can be installed with secedit.exe. If you want, you can open the inf file in a text editor and scroll until you see the `[Privilege Rights]` section.  Here is one for example.

```
[Privilege Rights]
SeDenyServiceLogonRight = *S-1-1-0,*S-1-5-19, KNUCKLE-DRAGGER
```

Run this command and reboot.  Edit .inf and .db names as appropriate.

```
    secedit.exe /configure /cfg C:\customsettings.inf /db C:\WINDOWS\security\Database\customsettings.db /quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a third party command line solution.  ntwrongs.exe

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/57557-NTWrongs%99

```
# Grant
.\NTWRONGS.exe -ID "Administrator" -Privilege "SeDenyServiceLogonRight"
# Revoke
.\NTWRONGS.exe -ID "Administrator" -Privilege "SeDenyServiceLogonRight" -Revoke
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a purely powershell method - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393118

```
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace LSA
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Management;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    using LSA_HANDLE = IntPtr;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        internal int Length;
        internal IntPtr RootDirectory;
        internal IntPtr ObjectName;
        internal int Attributes;
        internal IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
        internal IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING
    {
        internal ushort Length;
        internal ushort MaximumLength;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        internal string Buffer;
    }
    sealed class Win32Sec
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern uint LsaOpenPolicy(
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] SystemName,
        ref LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
        int AccessMask,
        out IntPtr PolicyHandle
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern uint LsaAddAccountRights(
        LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle,
        IntPtr pSID,
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] UserRights,
        int CountOfRights
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern int LsaLookupNames2(
        LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle,
        uint Flags,
        uint Count,
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] Names,
        ref IntPtr ReferencedDomains,
        ref IntPtr Sids
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaNtStatusToWinError(int NTSTATUS);

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaClose(IntPtr PolicyHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaFreeMemory(IntPtr Buffer);

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to grant "Log on as a service", "Log on as a batchjob", "Log on localy" etc.
    /// to a user.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class LsaWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_TRUST_INFORMATION
        {
            internal LSA_UNICODE_STRING Name;
            internal IntPtr Sid;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2
        {
            internal SidNameUse Use;
            internal IntPtr Sid;
            internal int DomainIndex;
            uint Flags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_REFERENCED_DOMAIN_LIST
        {
            internal uint Entries;
            internal LSA_TRUST_INFORMATION Domains;
        }

        enum SidNameUse : int
        {
            User = 1,
            Group = 2,
            Domain = 3,
            Alias = 4,
            KnownGroup = 5,
            DeletedAccount = 6,
            Invalid = 7,
            Unknown = 8,
            Computer = 9
        }

        enum Access : int
        {
            POLICY_READ = 0x20006,
            POLICY_ALL_ACCESS = 0x00F0FFF,
            POLICY_EXECUTE = 0X20801,
            POLICY_WRITE = 0X207F8
        }
        const uint STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED = 0xc0000022;
        const uint STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES = 0xc000009a;
        const uint STATUS_NO_MEMORY = 0xc0000017;

        IntPtr lsaHandle;

        public LsaWrapper()
            : this(null)
        { }
        // // local system if systemName is null
        public LsaWrapper(string systemName)
        {
            LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES lsaAttr;
            lsaAttr.RootDirectory = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.ObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.Attributes = 0;
            lsaAttr.SecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.SecurityQualityOfService = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES));
            lsaHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] system = null;
            if (systemName != null)
            {
                system = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
                system[0] = InitLsaString(systemName);
            }

            uint ret = Win32Sec.LsaOpenPolicy(system, ref lsaAttr,
            (int)Access.POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, out lsaHandle);
            if (ret == 0)
                return;
            if (ret == STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            if ((ret == STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) || (ret == STATUS_NO_MEMORY))
            {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            }
            throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)ret));
        }

        public void AddPrivileges(string account, string privilege)
        {
            IntPtr pSid = GetSIDInformation(account);
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] privileges = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
            privileges[0] = InitLsaString(privilege);
            uint ret = Win32Sec.LsaAddAccountRights(lsaHandle, pSid, privileges, 1);
            if (ret == 0)
                return;
            if (ret == STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            if ((ret == STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) || (ret == STATUS_NO_MEMORY))
            {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            }
            throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)ret));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (lsaHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32Sec.LsaClose(lsaHandle);
                lsaHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        ~LsaWrapper()
        {
            Dispose();
        }
        // helper functions

        IntPtr GetSIDInformation(string account)
        {
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] names = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
            LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2 lts;
            IntPtr tsids = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tdom = IntPtr.Zero;
            names[0] = InitLsaString(account);
            lts.Sid = IntPtr.Zero;
            Console.WriteLine("String account: {0}", names[0].Length);
            int ret = Win32Sec.LsaLookupNames2(lsaHandle, 0, 1, names, ref tdom, ref tsids);
            if (ret != 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError(ret));
            lts = (LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tsids,
            typeof(LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2));
            Win32Sec.LsaFreeMemory(tsids);
            Win32Sec.LsaFreeMemory(tdom);
            return lts.Sid;
        }

        static LSA_UNICODE_STRING InitLsaString(string s)
        {
            // Unicode strings max. 32KB
            if (s.Length > 0x7ffe)
                throw new ArgumentException("String too long");
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING lus = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING();
            lus.Buffer = s;
            lus.Length = (ushort)(s.Length * sizeof(char));
            lus.MaximumLength = (ushort)(lus.Length + sizeof(char));
            return lus;
        }
    }
    public class Editor
    {
        public static void AddPrivileges(string account, string privilege)
        {
            using (LsaWrapper lsaWrapper = new LsaWrapper())
            {
                lsaWrapper.AddPrivileges(account, privilege);
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

[LSA.Editor]::AddPrivileges("KNUCKLE-DRAGGER", "SeBatchLogonRight")
secpol.msc
```

Answer (score 0):

To build upon @Knuckle-Dragger's answer:

I couldn't add my user to the `secreatesymboliclinkprivilege` setting (**Computer Configuration** > **Windows Settings** > **Security Settings** > **Local Policies** > ** User Rights Assignment** > **Create symbolic links**), always with the error "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted", and it worked with his method, for my `DOMAIN\user` account from the `whoami` output:

```
SecEdit.exe /export /db C:\WINDOWS\security\Database\secedit.sdb /cfg config
# edited the file, added just ',DOMAIN\user' to this line:
# secreatesymboliclinkprivilege = *S-1-5-83-0,*S-1-5-32-544,DOMAIN\user
SecEdit.exe /configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg config
```