# Enabling a Local User Right assignment in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've asked a similar question like this before to get the Local User right in PowerShell of a certain domain user, now I would like to enable the right. There are a few rights I am looking to enable, but for this example I will use Logon as a Batch Job. Ntrights does not come with Windows Server 2008 by default, so I cannot use that method. The SID of the user is not passed from the program that I am using I cannot use secedit, but the domain and username are passed through so I can use that. I am stumped on an easy way to add multiple user rights without some arcane script. Is there a simple way to grant user rights without needing to download ntrights or without needing to know the SID of the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace LSA
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Management;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    using LSA_HANDLE = IntPtr;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        internal int Length;
        internal IntPtr RootDirectory;
        internal IntPtr ObjectName;
        internal int Attributes;
        internal IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
        internal IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING
    {
        internal ushort Length;
        internal ushort MaximumLength;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        internal string Buffer;
    }
    sealed class Win32Sec
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern uint LsaOpenPolicy(
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] SystemName,
        ref LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
        int AccessMask,
        out IntPtr PolicyHandle
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern uint LsaAddAccountRights(
        LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle,
        IntPtr pSID,
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] UserRights,
        int CountOfRights
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true),
        SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        internal static extern int LsaLookupNames2(
        LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle,
        uint Flags,
        uint Count,
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] Names,
        ref IntPtr ReferencedDomains,
        ref IntPtr Sids
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaNtStatusToWinError(int NTSTATUS);

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaClose(IntPtr PolicyHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern int LsaFreeMemory(IntPtr Buffer);

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to grant "Log on as a service", "Log on as a batchjob", "Log on localy" etc.
    /// to a user.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class LsaWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_TRUST_INFORMATION
        {
            internal LSA_UNICODE_STRING Name;
            internal IntPtr Sid;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2
        {
            internal SidNameUse Use;
            internal IntPtr Sid;
            internal int DomainIndex;
            uint Flags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct LSA_REFERENCED_DOMAIN_LIST
        {
            internal uint Entries;
            internal LSA_TRUST_INFORMATION Domains;
        }

        enum SidNameUse : int
        {
            User = 1,
            Group = 2,
            Domain = 3,
            Alias = 4,
            KnownGroup = 5,
            DeletedAccount = 6,
            Invalid = 7,
            Unknown = 8,
            Computer = 9
        }

        enum Access : int
        {
            POLICY_READ = 0x20006,
            POLICY_ALL_ACCESS = 0x00F0FFF,
            POLICY_EXECUTE = 0X20801,
            POLICY_WRITE = 0X207F8
        }
        const uint STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED = 0xc0000022;
        const uint STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES = 0xc000009a;
        const uint STATUS_NO_MEMORY = 0xc0000017;

        IntPtr lsaHandle;

        public LsaWrapper()
            : this(null)
        { }
        // // local system if systemName is null
        public LsaWrapper(string systemName)
        {
            LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES lsaAttr;
            lsaAttr.RootDirectory = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.ObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.Attributes = 0;
            lsaAttr.SecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.SecurityQualityOfService = IntPtr.Zero;
            lsaAttr.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES));
            lsaHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] system = null;
            if (systemName != null)
            {
                system = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
                system[0] = InitLsaString(systemName);
            }

            uint ret = Win32Sec.LsaOpenPolicy(system, ref lsaAttr,
            (int)Access.POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, out lsaHandle);
            if (ret == 0)
                return;
            if (ret == STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            if ((ret == STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) || (ret == STATUS_NO_MEMORY))
            {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            }
            throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)ret));
        }

        public void AddPrivileges(string account, string privilege)
        {
            IntPtr pSid = GetSIDInformation(account);
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] privileges = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
            privileges[0] = InitLsaString(privilege);
            uint ret = Win32Sec.LsaAddAccountRights(lsaHandle, pSid, privileges, 1);
            if (ret == 0)
                return;
            if (ret == STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
            if ((ret == STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) || (ret == STATUS_NO_MEMORY))
            {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            }
            throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError((int)ret));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (lsaHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32Sec.LsaClose(lsaHandle);
                lsaHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        ~LsaWrapper()
        {
            Dispose();
        }
        // helper functions

        IntPtr GetSIDInformation(string account)
        {
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] names = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
            LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2 lts;
            IntPtr tsids = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tdom = IntPtr.Zero;
            names[0] = InitLsaString(account);
            lts.Sid = IntPtr.Zero;
            Console.WriteLine("String account: {0}", names[0].Length);
            int ret = Win32Sec.LsaLookupNames2(lsaHandle, 0, 1, names, ref tdom, ref tsids);
            if (ret != 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(Win32Sec.LsaNtStatusToWinError(ret));
            lts = (LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tsids,
            typeof(LSA_TRANSLATED_SID2));
            Win32Sec.LsaFreeMemory(tsids);
            Win32Sec.LsaFreeMemory(tdom);
            return lts.Sid;
        }

        static LSA_UNICODE_STRING InitLsaString(string s)
        {
            // Unicode strings max. 32KB
            if (s.Length > 0x7ffe)
                throw new ArgumentException("String too long");
            LSA_UNICODE_STRING lus = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING();
            lus.Buffer = s;
            lus.Length = (ushort)(s.Length * sizeof(char));
            lus.MaximumLength = (ushort)(lus.Length + sizeof(char));
            return lus;
        }
    }
    public class Editor
    {
        public static void AddPrivileges(string account, string privilege)
        {
            using (LsaWrapper lsaWrapper = new LsaWrapper())
            {
                lsaWrapper.AddPrivileges(account, privilege);
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

[LSA.Editor]::AddPrivileges("KNUCKLE-DRAGGER", "SeBatchLogonRight")
secpol.msc
```

This snip can find sids by itself if anyone has the need.

```
    Function Get-Sid ($User,$Domain){
    If ($Domain -eq $null){$Domain = $ENV:ComputerName}
    (Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount | select SID,Name,Domain | where {$_.Name -eq "$User"} | where {$_.Domain -eq "$Domain"} |Select-Object SID).SID
    }
```

Comment: That's a heck of a lot of code, thanks. Wish I had enough rep so I could upvote that.

Comment: I've seen essentially this same chunk of code, sometimes with a method that enumerates the rights, several times now. Any idea from whom/where it originates?

Comment: [...time passes...] I just found this thread, with comments in the code which may lead back to the original sources. Plus it has the enumeration method. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d8d1f997-84d1-4e7b-9c66-c609f780f214/query-account-privileges-for-context-running-script

Comment: Now just have figure out how to remove a Right.