# Take Ownership and set access to everyone in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, file, visual-studio-2013, directory

So, my issue is as follows: I am trying to replace the use of the batch file (Takeown.gib (gib because VS lets me extract it easier that way) in https://github.com/PFCKrutonium/Windows-10-Login-Background-Changer) using VB Code. Basically I need to take ownership of the directory and all containing files, as well as setting permissions so that either everyone or just admin can edit the directory and containing files.

The code I am looking at, at this moment, is:

```
    Dim User As String = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name
    Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(SysResources)
    Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
    FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))
    FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)
```

Which doesn't seem to particularly work, since it only does half the job, and it doesn't even manage to do that to be honest.

Thanks for any insight/help you can give me!

Comment: Gonna be tricky Kruto, you'll need to first enable the "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege" in your token/session before you can take ownership.  Once you've got the privilege you can assign the ownership from VB, then finally you'll be able to add permissions on the ACL.  Find C# / Powershell privilege escalation examples here.  Likely you can convert the C# to VB (or not)   http://stackoverflow.com/a/26645034/3093031

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, doesn't running as administrator do that anyway?

Comment: No no no.  It does not work that way (ostensibly for your safety)  Open a CMD as Administrator and type "whoami /priv" to verify it is disabled.

Comment: So how does a tool like takeown / icacls work?

And could you suggest maybe a way I can improve the batch file so it works instead?

Comment: Did you see the large 200 line function in the link.  I suspect the takeown tool has a built-in function to increase your privilege, very similar to that, working behind the scenes.  One that temporarily increases your privilege until it finishes it's task.   You'll need to replicate that privilege escalaton if you want to abandon takeown.exe.

Comment: Try this.  I think object inheritance and container inheritance went missing.  `ICACLS %windir%\SystemResources\Windows.UI.Logon /T /grant *S-1-5-32-544:(OI)(CI)F`

Comment: Thanks for the fix :)

Answer (score 0):

See Knuckle-Dragger comments - solved it by continuing to use batch, and fixed the batch.